# jQuery Functions not executing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I have three `<ul>`'s which I want to merge and turn into a slider (I'm using the [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/)).  It is something like...

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="products-grid">
        <li>Product 1</li>
        <li>Product 2</li>
        <li>Product 3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="products-grid">
        <li>Product 4</li>
        <li>Product 5</li>
        <li>Product 6</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="products-grid">
        <li>Product 7</li>
        <li>Product 8</li>
        <li>Product 9</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I execute the below lines of jQuery in the chrome console, one line at a time, everything works perfectly.

```
jQuery('ul.products-grid').children('li').appendTo('ul.products-grid:first'); 
jQuery('ul.products-grid').not(':first').remove(); 
jQuery('ul.products-grid').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 200,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 3,
    slideMargin: 10
});
```

But when I try to execute the jQuery in the php/html template or in the chrome console all at once, only the first line executes and I'm left with...

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="products-grid">
        <li>Product 1</li>
        <li>Product 2</li>
        <li>Product 3</li>
        <li>Product 4</li>
        <li>Product 5</li>
        <li>Product 6</li>
        <li>Product 7</li>
        <li>Product 8</li>
        <li>Product 9</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="products-grid">
    </ul>
    <ul class="products-grid">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any idea how I can fix this?  It seems to have something to do with the order in which the code is executing.

### UPDATE

I noticed that in the console if I put the debugger on just before the code executes I get the below error after the

's have been appended.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: optionsPrice is not defined    bundle.js 110
```

This must be causing some conflict.  Here is the full function from bundle.js

```
reloadPrice: function() {
    var calculatedPrice = 0;
    var dispositionPrice = 0;
    var includeTaxPrice = 0;
    for (var option in this.config.selected) {
        if (this.config.options[option]) {
            for (var i=0; i < this.config.selected[option].length; i++) {
                var prices = this.selectionPrice(option, this.config.selected[option][i]);
                calculatedPrice += Number(prices[0]);
                dispositionPrice += Number(prices[1]);
                includeTaxPrice += Number(prices[2]);
            }
        }
    }

    var event = $(document).fire('bundle:reload-price', {
        price: calculatedPrice,
        priceInclTax: includeTaxPrice,
        dispositionPrice: dispositionPrice,
        bundle: this
    });
    if (!event.noReloadPrice) {
        optionsPrice.specialTaxPrice = 'true';  // line 110
        optionsPrice.changePrice('bundle', calculatedPrice);
        optionsPrice.changePrice('nontaxable', dispositionPrice);
        optionsPrice.changePrice('priceInclTax', includeTaxPrice);
        optionsPrice.reload();
    }

    return calculatedPrice;
},
```

And within the

's there is a script tag that have. . .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var bundle = new Product.Bundle({"options":{"98":{"selections":{"2307":{"qty":1,"customQty":"0","price":2.5,"priceInclTax":1.88,"priceExclTax":1.88,"priceValue":0,"priceType":"0","tierPrice":{"32000-7":{"price_id":"738","website_.......
```

The full stack trace show's my line of code beforehand.

Comment: The code is synchronous so the order of execution should not be an issue. If only the first line of code is executing then it sounds likely that you have an error. Have you checked the console?

Comment: Maybe add a $(document).ready(function(){//jquerylines});

Comment: it's running fine for me, even outside of document.ready

Comment: don't run it from console but wrap it with dom ready and reload.

Comment: The first line of your code appends some elements to their parent; it should not be an issue, but still try to avoid it: `jQuery('ul.products-grid').not(':first').children('li').appendTo('ul.products-grid:first');`. You might also want to try appending everything to a hidden DIV, destroying all the ULs and recreating only one.

Comment: I tried this in jsfiddle, excluding the third line of code and it did what it has to. Here's the jsfiddle:  `https://jsfiddle.net/k58sufqb/` The second and third ul elements get removed

Comment: @MikayilAbdullayev, I added the third line with and the bxslider as an external resource and the third line does not execute

Comment: I've edited the `https://jsfiddle.net/k58sufqb/`and now it even adds the bxslider. So you need to show us some more code. The problem is definitely not with this part of the code. You might have something conflicting with this code.

Comment: Ohh, sorry, the exterlan resources get removed when not saved. I'll fix it now.

Comment: I updated my question with more detail, it does indeed seem to be some kind of JavaScript conflict

Comment: Well you're using an `optionsPrice` variable, but I don't see it referenced anywhere else. I guess it is part of `bundle`? Could it be `bundle.option[x].price?`

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your jquery code into the jquery ready function:

```js
$(function() {
  jQuery('ul.products-grid').children('li').appendTo('ul.products-grid:first'); 
  jQuery('ul.products-grid').not(':first').remove(); 
  jQuery('ul.products-grid').bxSlider({
      slideWidth: 200,
      minSlides: 1,
      maxSlides: 3,
      slideMargin: 10
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul class="products-grid">
          <li>Product 1</li>
          <li>Product 2</li>
          <li>Product 3</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="products-grid">
          <li>Product 4</li>
          <li>Product 5</li>
          <li>Product 6</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="products-grid">
          <li>Product 7</li>
          <li>Product 8</li>
          <li>Product 9</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `$(handler)` is a shortcut to the `ready` function. i.e: invoking the jquery object as a function and passing a function as the parameter is equivalent to `$( document ).ready( handler )`

Comment: @SamBauwens, that didn't work for me.  I also tried it with `jQuery( document ).ready(function() { });`

Comment: Actually, it works if I put images in there : https://plnkr.co/edit/6XXYcMenWLr7gKkLaoxZ?p=preview

Comment: I updated my question with more detail, it does indeed seem to be some kind of JavaScript conflict

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<ul class="products-grid">
    <li>Product 1</li>
    <li>Product 2</li>
    <li>Product 3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="products-grid">
    <li>Product 4</li>
    <li>Product 5</li>
    <li>Product 6</li>
</ul>
<ul class="products-grid">
    <li>Product 7</li>
    <li>Product 8</li>
    <li>Product 9</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
    body{color:#000;}
li {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.wrapper{
  height: 200px;
  background: #d8d8d8;
}
```

**JS**

```
    jQuery('ul.products-grid').children('li').appendTo('.wrapper ul.products-grid:first'); 
jQuery('.wrapper ul.products-grid').not(':first').remove(); 
jQuery('ul.products-grid').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 200,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 3,
    slideMargin: 10
});
```

Please check solved answer in my codepen profile.
http://codepen.io/prashen/pen/pyjRvo

Comment: @Holy Hey! Did you checked this? If it's working for you then reply.

Comment: thanks but this did not solve my issue.  I updated my question with more detail, it  seem to be some kind of JavaScript conflict